# When can we use "is" at the end of sentence?

Tags: auxiliary-verbs

> You must leave the furniture as it **is**. you mustn't move anything.

When can we use *the verb to be*  at the end of sentence?

**UPDATE:**

> The verb be is used in the following patterns:
>
> 1. with a noun:
>
> My mother is a teacher. Bill Clinton was the president of the US.
>
> 2. with an adjective:
>
> This soup is very tasty. The children were good.
>
> 2.1 with the -ing form to make the continuous aspect
>
> We were walking down the street. Everything was wet. It had been
>   raining for hours.
>
> 2.2 with the -ed form to make the passive voice
>
> The house was built in 1890. The street is called Montagu Street. This
>   car was made in Japan.
>
> 3. with a prepositional phrase:
>
> John and his wife are from Manchester. The flowers are on the table.
>
> [British Council](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/verbs/verb-be)

In the above description, the *to be verbs* is followed by adjective or verb.

So, When can we use *the verb to be* without adjective or verb?

Comment: The question is too broad to answer. Please explain why and in what circumstances you think it might not be appropriate to end a sentence with "is".

Comment: The question was updated.

Answer (score -1):

When it is appropriate.

> It is.

This is a correct sentence.

> Is he home? Yes, he is.

These are correct sentences.

> You can be here whenever I am.

This is a correct sentence. I am (here). The (here) is implied, and can be written, but it is not required.

Comment: Thank you, What can we put between brackets in my case.  "You must leave the furniture as it is (___)"

Comment: I misread your question. I used the parentheses to show the part of the sentence which is implied, but not written. Let me revise it to include "is" examples.

Comment: So, When can we use the verb to be without adjective or verb?

All you need is a subject and a verb. I am. You are. He is. They are.